# Globalisation in WPF .Net7 Is Microsoft.Extensions.Localization the way to go?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

In legacy 4.x WPF Application I used WPFLocalizeExtension with ResX-Manager.

While moving ahead. New App written in .net7 need globalisation.

Is to use Microsoft.Extensions.Localization in WPF (also XAMARIN/MAUI) the way to go?

Comment: By ResX do you mean compiled resources read by `ResourceManager` or processing actual .resx files during runtime? If the latter, there is [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#dynamic-resource-management) library (disclaimer: written by me) that has read-write .resx files support on all platforms, including Xamarin and MAUI. I already [offered](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54657#issuecomment-896372843) it to be migrated into .NET, until then you can use it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I prefer is to use resource dictionaries rather than resx.

The deciding factor to me is that they may be dynamically loaded. You can merge uncompiled xaml as a resource dictionary. You can get a string from a service and parse it into a resource dictionary.

It also readily adapts to gradually adding translations.

How I do this is make all text use dynamicresource and a key.

There is a base default resource dictionary initially merged in app.xaml. That's always been English in anything I've worked on. Which includes German and French owned businesses, perhaps counter intuitively.

I then have another resource dictionary per language. These have matching keys but obviously different strings.
Merge in the appropriate user language resource dictionary to application resources and everything turns to that language.

A sort of bonus of this is the same principle can be used for branding of white label products, iconography etc. You "just" have another overlay of resource dictionary merging.

In multi nationals it's quite common to have just english for any super user / administrator views.